# Intermittent errors that go away after a few minutes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Everyday, I'm seeing errors come in that go away on their own after a few minutes. Usually they seem related to Cloud SQL but I've also seen SSL errors:

1) "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 95"

2) HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /o/oauth2/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:852)'),))

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this? Or tips on how to diagnose? It almost seems like a service is restarting and get's resolved on it's own.

Comment: The first issue may be internal Cloud SQL issue and I recommend you to open a support ticket for it - https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/ . The second one, may be related to the first one. It can also be a versioning related issue depending on your workflow. You can see a similar issue here : https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3006 . Anyhow unless you provide more details ( workflow, code etc..) your question is almost impossible to be answered.

Comment: @andrei what details would be helpful? These errors are only showing up momentarily during those short “outages”. If it was an issue with workflow or packages the error would happen all the time, right?

Comment: For example the code where you are managing the connection. But, in case the issue is intermittent, I recommend you to open a support case if you are entitled or, if you are not, you can open a public issue, providing all the details you can - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0.   There are good chances for the issue not to be exactly on your side, if it is intermittent.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiTigau I will open a support ticket.